# redirect to other controller with variables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

May I ask your help how to redirect with variables in it. here is my code.

```
function new_content(){
    $this->output->set_status_header(200);
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $subj_id = $this->input->post('subj_id');
    $mod_id = $this->input->post('mod_id');
    $lesson_id = $this->input->post('lesson_id');

    $sort_id = rand(100,999);

    $data = array(
        'subj_id'   => $subj_id,
        'mod_id'    => $mod_id,
        'lesson_id' => $lesson_id,
        'sort_id'   => $sort_id
        );
    $create = $this->mdl_lc->_insert($data);
    // $link = base_url().'lesson_content/edit/'.$subj_id.'/'.$mod_id.'/'.$lesson_id.'/'.$sort_id;
    // echo base_url().'lesson_content/edit/'.$subj_id.'/'.$mod_id.'/'.$lesson_id.'/'.$sort_id;
    redirect('lesson_content/edit/'.$subj_id.'/'.$mod_id.'/'.$lesson_id.'/'.$sort_id);
}

function edit(){
    $subj_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $mod_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $lesson_id = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $sort_id = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $data['subj_id'] = $subj_id;
    $data['mod_id'] = $mod_id;
    $data['lesson_id'] = $lesson_id;
    $data['sort_id'] = $sort_id;
    $data['title'] = 'Lesson Content';
    $this->load->view('lesson_content_display',$data);
}
```

note:

1. lesson_content is a controller.
2. edit is a function.
3. the rest are the variables that i'm trying to include with the redirect.

when I do some Inspect Element, the result is there but it wont redirect to the link that i'm trying to go.

Comment: Can you show us the lesson_content::edit function?

Comment: i feel bad about this. what I did after the return value of  a json i reload it and view the newly created item. :|

Comment: I think your code should work.what problem you getting?it does not redirect? if redirect what link you see at the address bar

Comment: yes, that's what I'm thinking too, it should work but the thing is it doesn't want to redirect. no error at all. the link should go this way. www.url.com/lesson_content/edit/1/1/1/1

Comment: solved! I just used json to redirect the page. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass URI segments straight to the edit function as parameters.

Like this;

```
public function edit($subject_id = '', $mod_id = '', $lesson_id = '', $sort_id = '')
{
    if ($subject_id == '' OR $mod_id = '' OR $lesson_id = '' OR $sort_id = '')
    {
      // IF anything is empty?
      show_error('Something went wrong...');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
           'subj_id' => $subject_id,
           'mod_id' => $mod_id,
           'lesson_id' => $lesson_id,
           'sort_id' => $sort_id
        );

        $this->load->view('lesson_content_display', $data);
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope, sorry. I got some if else to view certain part of the view inside my lesson_content_display

Comment: Did you fix my typo on the load view function?

Comment: nope. I really need to reload the page with that redirect. I need load it because I will be calling that sort_id from my view with this $ls_query = Modules::run('lesson_content/get_lscontent',$subj_id,$mod_id,$lesson_id,$sort_id);  and do some foreach to fill in all the fields that the user need to edit.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What URL are you been redirected too?

Comment: No error at all. insertion of new content is successful it's just that it doesn't want to redirect. after saving I need to redirect it to load the new data. hmm i even used the old style of header and some javascript still doesn't want to redirect. and as I do Inspect Element, I can see the page where it suppose to go.

Answer (score 0):

inside my controller function

```
$link = base_url().'lesson_content/edit/'.$subj_id.'/'.$mod_id.'/'.$lesson_id.'/'.$sort_id;
    $jdata['redirect_url'] = $link;
    $jdata['message'] = 'You have successfully created new content!';
    $jdata['result']  = "SUCCESS";                  
     echo json_encode($jdata); 
     exit();
```

and here is some script in my view

```
<script>
    function create_new(){
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('lesson_content/new_content'); ?>',
             {
                subj_id        : $('#subj_id').val(),
                mod_id         : $('#mod_id').val(),
                lesson_id      : $('#lesson_id').val()
             },
             function(data){


                  if(data.result=='SUCCESS'){
                    // $('#lesson_created').val();

                    $('#lesson_created').html(data.message);
                      //$('#lesson_created').show();
                      $('#lesson_created').fadeTo( 1500, 5.0, function(){
                        $('#lesson_created').fadeOut(4000);
                            // setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();}, 2500);
                            window.location.href = data.redirect_url
                      });

                  }

            },'json'
        );
    }
</script>
```

i just add this line of code to run the json result: window.location.href = data.redirect_url